# How to design system by Domain Driven Design?

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices, bounded-contexts

I would like to ask to more philosophical question. Topic is DDD and microservices. DDD recognizes bounded context. If I understand correctly then each bounded context is small part of whole system. For example there could be ordering context and invoicing context. Each context works with customers but ordering context cannot know about invoicing setting and invoicing cannot know about ordering setting. Does it means that there will be two customer microservices, each for each context? 
Second question is: If I have order microservice can I load customer data to evaluate some conditions, to check customer can create new order, directly from database or can I need to access through customer microservice?

Thanks for your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to know that the same concept can mean different things in different contexts. For example in order context the entity customer probably mean a person who you can deliver things and because of that the order-customer will have attributes such as address, prefered time to deliver.. etc.

However if we look a customer in invoicing context, it will mean a person who you can get paid, and because of that it will have attributes like, credit card number, paypal account, prefered payment type, etc..

Said that, and to answer your first question, I think it is no necessary to have two different customer services, you should have one customer service preferible on its own bounded context that will be called when a customer wants to update and query his own settings, and different views or projection entities for customers both in order and invoice contexts with the informarion that you need to perform the operations in those contexts.

In a event driven design, this entites will be updated accordingly to the service context by suscribing to the update customer events, so when any modification to deliver or payment options are produced, this entities will update.

Answering your second question, to access the database of one service directly from other service is never an option, it will cause the two services will be couple to the same database so the customer service wont be able to manage its database according to its own needs because other service knows and depends on the database structure (tables, columns, relations.. etc). The solution here is, if the data you need is no directly related with the process or if there is no performance strong requirements you can query the service every time you need the information.

However if the information is part of the other service process or there is need of high performance the best solution is have a local copy of that info as I said before when I was talking about order and invoice customers and update them when any changes are made. This can be even a cache if there isn't an event driven approach.